# Automapper to create new row with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, automapper

Using automap to map the many to many relationship.

Consider the below example

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int age{get;set;}
    public List<Details> Details {get;set;}
}

public class Details
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Designation{get;set;}
}
```

I want to automap the above entities into new DTO object like

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public int age{get;set;}
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Designation{get;set;}
}
```

So all the entries in the list of customer details should be considered as new row to the customerDTO. How to do this ?

Comment: So if you have 1 `Customer` object with 10 `Details`, you expect to get 10 `CustomerDto` objects?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a `Customer` object and you want to map it to a `List<CustomerDto>`. Such list will contain a single item for each detail in the `Customer` object.

Here is one way to do it:

First, create two mappings, one mapping from `Customer` to `CustomerDto`, and the other one from `Details` to `CustomerDto`.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Details, CustomerDto>();
```

Now, let's say you have a `Customer` object in variable `customer`, you can do the following:

```
List<CustomerDto> dtos = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<CustomerDto>>(customer.Details);

foreach (var dto in dtos)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(customer, dto);
}
```